# why is deserializion of returned Json into class object failing C#?

Tags: c#, json, api, request, deserialization

I'm working on a telegram bot that reports transaction information to users in a channel. The transaction information is pulled via an HTTP request using standard "application/json" response.

The application does two passthroughs: the first one returns the current market price for tokens it checks. The second one, provides all new transactions that occurred after the last checked timestamp. Here is the current code, minus the API keys. API Keys were removed for privacy.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Exceptions;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TelegramBotGeneric
{

    class PriceObject
    {
    public string address { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public double volume_24h { get; set; }
    public double liquidity { get; set; }
    public double volume_24h_usd { get; set; }
    public double liquidty_usd { get; set; }
    public double price_usd { get; set; }
    public double volume_24h_delta { get; set; }
    public double liquidity_24H_delta { get; set; }
    public double volume_24h_delta_usd { get; set; }
    public double liquidty_24h_delta_usd { get; set; }
    public double  price_25h_delta_usd{ get; set; }
    public double timestamp { get; set; }
    public PriceObject()
    {
        //default CTOR
    }
}

class tokensTransfered
{
    public string address { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string symbol { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string amm { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string network { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public double price_usd { get; set; }
    public double price_eth { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public double amount_in { get; set; }
    public double amount_out { get; set; }

    public tokensTransfered()
    {
        //defaut CTOR
    }
}

class returnedTransaction
{
    public string amm { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public long chain_id { get; set; }
    public string direction { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string transaction_address { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public double timestamp { get; set; }
    public double block_number { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string sender { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public double amount_usd { get; set; }
    public List<tokensTransfered> tokens_in { get; set; } = new List<tokensTransfered>();
    public List<tokensTransfered> tokens_out { get; set; } = new List<tokensTransfered>();
    public string pair_address { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string wallet_address { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string wallet_category { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string transaction_type { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    public returnedTransaction()
    {
        //default CTOR
    }
}
public class TelegramBot
{
    //Readonly Declarators for API Information and Query Strings
    private static readonly string TB_BASE_IMAGES_DIRECTORY = @Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\images";
    private static readonly string TB_API_ADDR = "https://api.dev.dex.guru/v1/chain/137/tokens/";
    private static readonly string DEXGURU_MARKET_API_KEY = 
        "/market?api-key=";
    private static readonly string DEXGURU_TRANSACTIONS_API_KEY = 
        "/transactions?api-key=";
    private static readonly string TELEGRAM_BOT_API_KEY = "";
    private static readonly int TB_MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_POLLING = 10;
    private static readonly int TB_MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_REFRESH_ON_ERROR = 15;

    //declarators for TelegramBot API
    private static TelegramBotClient client = new TelegramBotClient(TELEGRAM_BOT_API_KEY);
    private static CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    //private static IEnumerable<BotCommand> botCommands;

    //storage containers for Image URL and Contract addresses
    public static Dictionary<string, string> tbBotCheckableContractAddresses { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public static string[] tbBotImgFileURL { get; set; } = new string[] { };

    //variables for time calculation
    private static DateTime lastUpdateTime = new();
    private static int tbCurrentTimeBetweenPolling = 0;
    private static bool tbFirstPassthrough = true;
    private static bool tbContinuePolling = true;
    private static double tbTransactionLastCheckedTimestamp = 0;


    //variables for HTTPRequest Information
    private static HttpClient tbHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    private static Dictionary<string, double> tbApiReturnedPrices { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    private static Dictionary<string, double> tbApiPreviousPrices { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    private static string tbCurrentlyPolledAddress = "";


    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        lastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
        tbAddAddressesToCheckist();
        tbAddDefaultPrices();
        tbCurrentTimeBetweenPolling = TB_MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_POLLING;
        do
        { 
            if(tbFirstPassthrough)
            {
                //first we want to check prices
                await tbCompletePriceUpdate();

                //TEST - output to Telegram the price of TDL
                /*Message statusMessage = await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: -765409926,
                 text: "The Current Price of Tidal" + Environment.NewLine +
                 "**TDL/USD**:  $" + Regex.Escape(tbApiReturnedPrices["TDL"].ToString() + " per TDL.")
                 + Environment.NewLine + "**TDL/WETH**: "
                 + Regex.Escape((tbApiReturnedPrices["WETH"] * ((tbApiReturnedPrices["TDL"] / tbApiReturnedPrices["WETH"])* 100)).ToString() + " WETH per TDL. (WETH = " + tbApiReturnedPrices["WETH"] + ")")
                 + Environment.NewLine + "**TDL/WBTC**: "
                 + Regex.Escape((tbApiReturnedPrices["WBTC"] * ((tbApiReturnedPrices["TDL"] / tbApiReturnedPrices["WBTC"])* 100)).ToString() + " WBTC per TDL. (WBTC = " + tbApiReturnedPrices["WBTC"] + ")"),
                 parseMode: ParseMode.MarkdownV2,
                 disableNotification: true, cancellationToken: cts.Token);
                lastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;*/

                await tbFetchNewProcessedOrders(tbBotCheckableContractAddresses["WETH"]);


            }
            else if((DateTime.Now - lastUpdateTime).Minutes >= TB_MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_POLLING)
            {
                //first we want to check prices
                await tbCompletePriceUpdate();

                //TEST - output to Telegram the price of TDL
                /*Message statusMessage = await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: -765409926,
                 text: "The Current Price of Tidal" + Environment.NewLine +
                 "**TDL/USD**:  $" + Regex.Escape(tbApiReturnedPrices["TDL"].ToString() + " per TDL.")
                 + Environment.NewLine + "**TDL/WETH**: "
                 + Regex.Escape((tbApiReturnedPrices["WETH"] * ((tbApiReturnedPrices["TDL"] / tbApiReturnedPrices["WETH"])* 100)).ToString() + " WETH per TDL. (WETH = " + tbApiReturnedPrices["WETH"] + ")")
                 + Environment.NewLine + "**TDL/WBTC**: "
                 + Regex.Escape((tbApiReturnedPrices["WBTC"] * ((tbApiReturnedPrices["TDL"] / tbApiReturnedPrices["WBTC"])* 100)).ToString() + " WBTC per TDL. (WBTC = " + tbApiReturnedPrices["WBTC"] + ")"),
                 parseMode: ParseMode.MarkdownV2,
                 disableNotification: true, cancellationToken: cts.Token);
                lastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;*/
                await tbFetchNewProcessedOrders(tbBotCheckableContractAddresses["WETH"]);
            }
            else
            {
                //something here
                await tbFetchNewProcessedOrders(tbBotCheckableContractAddresses["WETH"]);
            }
        } while (tbContinuePolling);
    }

    private static void tbAddAddressesToCheckist()
    {
        tbBotCheckableContractAddresses.Add("TDL", "0x896219cfa4dF4AB30A418355928724d8B5D25FAC");
        //tbBotCheckableContractAddresses.Add("WMATIC", "0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270");
        //tbBotCheckableContractAddresses.Add("WBNB", "0x3BA4c387f786bFEE076A58914F5Bd38d668B42c3");
        tbBotCheckableContractAddresses.Add("WETH", "0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619");
        tbBotCheckableContractAddresses.Add("WBTC", "0x1BFD67037B42Cf73acF2047067bd4F2C47D9BfD6");
    }

    public static void tbAddDefaultPrices()
    {
        tbApiReturnedPrices.Add("TDL", 0);
        //tbApiReturnedPrices.Add("WMATIC", 0);
        //tbApiReturnedPrices.Add("WBNB", 0);
        tbApiReturnedPrices.Add("WETH", 0);
        tbApiReturnedPrices.Add("WBTC", 0);
        tbApiPreviousPrices = tbApiReturnedPrices;
    }

    private static void tbHttpClientSetup(string address)
    {
        tbHttpClient = new HttpClient();
        tbHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        tbHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        tbCurrentlyPolledAddress = address;
    }

    private static async Task tbHttpClientGetPriceData()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await tbHttpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(TB_API_ADDR + tbCurrentlyPolledAddress + DEXGURU_MARKET_API_KEY));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            try
            {
                PriceObject jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceObject>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                if (jsonResponse == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException();
                tbApiReturnedPrices[(tbBotCheckableContractAddresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == tbCurrentlyPolledAddress).Key)] = jsonResponse.price_usd;
                Console.WriteLine("Retrieved Price Update For Contract " + tbCurrentlyPolledAddress);

            }
                
            catch (Exception ex) when(ex is ArgumentException || ex is NullReferenceException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error getting transaction updates For Contract " + tbCurrentlyPolledAddress + ". Error: "
                    + ex.Message);
                Message statusMessage = await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: -765409926,
                text: Regex.Escape("Error: An error occured when getting transaction data from source. Trying again in "
                + TB_MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_REFRESH_ON_ERROR + "Minutes. Status: " + ex.HResult), parseMode: ParseMode.MarkdownV2,
                disableNotification: true, cancellationToken: cts.Token);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error getting transaction updates For Contract " + tbCurrentlyPolledAddress + ". Status: "
                    + response.StatusCode);
            Message statusMessage = await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: -765409926,
            text: Regex.Escape("Error: An error occured when getting transaction data from source. Trying again in "
            + TB_MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_REFRESH_ON_ERROR + "Minutes. Status: " + response.StatusCode), parseMode: ParseMode.MarkdownV2,
            disableNotification: true, cancellationToken: cts.Token);
        }
    }

    private static async Task tbCompletePriceUpdate()
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in tbBotCheckableContractAddresses)
        {
            tbHttpClientSetup(pair.Value);
            await tbHttpClientGetPriceData();

            tbApiPreviousPrices = tbApiReturnedPrices;
        }
    }

    private static async Task tbFetchNewProcessedOrders(string address)
    {
        //setup the HTTP Client
        tbHttpClientSetup(address);
        string polledAddress = tbBotCheckableContractAddresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == address).Key;
        returnedTransaction[] transactions;

        //get the response
        HttpResponseMessage response = await tbHttpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(TB_API_ADDR + tbCurrentlyPolledAddress + DEXGURU_TRANSACTIONS_API_KEY));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (response != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                transactions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<returnedTransaction[]>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                if (transactions == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException();

                foreach(returnedTransaction transaction in transactions)
                {
                    
                    if(tbTransactionLastCheckedTimestamp == 0)
                    {
                        tbTransactionLastCheckedTimestamp = transaction.timestamp;

                        Console.WriteLine(
                            (transaction.amount_usd / tbApiReturnedPrices[polledAddress]) + " " + polledAddress +
                            " was purchased for $" + transaction.amount_usd + ".");
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (tbTransactionLastCheckedTimestamp < transaction.timestamp)
                            tbTransactionLastCheckedTimestamp = transaction.timestamp;

                        Console.WriteLine(
                            ((double)transaction.amount_usd / tbApiReturnedPrices[polledAddress]) + " " + polledAddress +
                            " was purchased for $" + transaction.amount_usd + ".");
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) when (ex is ArgumentException || ex is NullReferenceException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error getting transaction updates For Contract " + tbCurrentlyPolledAddress + ". Error: "
                    + ex.Message);
                Message statusMessage = await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: -765409926,
                text: Regex.Escape("Error: An error occured when getting transaction data from source. Trying again in "
                + TB_MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_REFRESH_ON_ERROR + "Minutes. Status: " + ex.HResult), parseMode: ParseMode.MarkdownV2,
                disableNotification: true, cancellationToken: cts.Token);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error getting transaction updates For Contract " + tbCurrentlyPolledAddress + ". Status: "
                    + response.StatusCode);
            Message statusMessage = await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: -765409926,
            text: Regex.Escape("Error: An error occured when getting transaction data from source. Trying again in "
            + TB_MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_REFRESH_ON_ERROR + "Minutes. Status: " + response.StatusCode), parseMode: ParseMode.MarkdownV2,
            disableNotification: true, cancellationToken: cts.Token);
        }
    }

    private static async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Only process Message updates: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message
        if (update.Type != UpdateType.Message)
            return;
        // Only process text messages
        if (update.Message!.Type != MessageType.Text)
            return;

        var chatId = update.Message.Chat.Id;
        var messageText = update.Message.Text;

        Console.WriteLine($"Received a '{messageText}' message in chat {chatId}.");

        // Echo received message text
        Message sentMessage = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
            chatId: chatId,
            text: "You said:\n" + messageText,
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }

    private Task HandleErrorAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var ErrorMessage = exception switch
        {
            ApiRequestException apiRequestException
                => $"Telegram API Error:\n[{apiRequestException.ErrorCode}]\n{apiRequestException.Message}",
            _ => exception.ToString()
        };

        Console.WriteLine(ErrorMessage);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
}
```

The problem here is with the function in the above code:

```
private static async Task tbFetchNewProcessedOrders(string address)
```

This function is able to return the json data correctly from the API call, which also returns **Status Code: 200 [OK]**

However, when i try to deserialize the data into an array of class objects, it throws an error:

*Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'TelegramBotGeneric.returnedTransaction[]' because the type requires a JSON array*

This is although the HTTP request DOES return a json array, and the function

```
private static async Task tbHttpClientGetPriceData()
```

also deserializes in the same way, with the exception of it not needing a array of classes as it only returns 1 token price per request, and does not fail when deserializing.

Any ideas as to what is going on? am i missing something? any and all help would be appreciated.

Edit: a copy of the Json results:

```
{"total":10000,"data":[{"amm":"waultswap","chain_id":137,"direction":"in","transaction_address":"0xfd8baf557efb178b15fa248ae220d133f0f9fc6d80ca45006eb7f2302fee729c","timestamp":1645650607,"block_number":25270535,"to":"0xcecc7e26d0987281b7da1e3c757161ed6b20af6f","sender":"0x79bafc10542ba08593b2d775d64ed197b0b9a5f9","amount_usd":9.704910550601628,"tokens_in":[{"address":"0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174","symbol":"USDC","amm":"waultswap","network":"polygon","price_usd":0.9997410796727977,"price_eth":0.6633868277838665,"amount":9.707424,"amount_in":9.707424,"amount_out":0.0}],"tokens_out":[{"address":"0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619","symbol":"WETH","amm":"waultswap","network":"polygon","price_usd":2623.3377574906485,"price_eth":1740.2877131473633,"amount":0.003696525837357276,"amount_in":0.0,"amount_out":0.003696525837357276}],"pair_address":"0xd928ce1d0f2642e44615768761c0f00c23e0d588","wallet_address":"0x779010626fd0c88b6013e802478f07d84de5c4d7","wallet_category":"bot","transaction_type":"swap"},{"amm":"quickswap","chain_id":137,"direction":"out","transaction_address":"0xfd8baf557efb178b15fa248ae220d133f0f9fc6d80ca45006eb7f2302fee729c","timestamp":1645650607,"block_number":25270535,"to":"0xd8d51ea2edca2c2ea15a053a5730f559d79a1570","sender":"0x79bafc10542ba08593b2d775d64ed197b0b9a5f9","amount_usd":9.719504105372957,"tokens_in":[{"address":"0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619","symbol":"WETH","amm":"quickswap","network":"polygon","price_usd":2629.3618746410916,"price_eth":1744.2848570041135,"amount":0.003696525837357276,"amount_in":0.003696525837357276,"amount_out":0.0}],"tokens_out":[{"address":"0x7f426f6dc648e50464a0392e60e1bb465a67e9cf","symbol":"PAUTO","amm":"quickswap","network":"polygon","price_usd":387.73659420086454,"price_eth":257.2194707368818,"amount":0.02503545234060058,"amount_in":0.0,"amount_out":0.02503545234060058}],"pair_address":"0xcecc7e26d0987281b7da1e3c757161ed6b20af6f","wallet_address":"0x779010626fd0c88b6013e802478f07d84de5c4d7","wallet_category":"bot","transaction_type":"swap"},{"amm":"uniswap_v3","chain_id":137,"direction":"out","transaction_address":"0x5d0bed394c1a35dcc12a70863b499807f1994cd2b3d4f53f3ebadebf4cf02018","timestamp":1645650603,"block_number":25270534,"to":"0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45","sender":"0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45","amount_usd":24187.585904394073,"tokens_in":[{"address":"0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619","symbol":"WETH","amm":"uniswap_v3","network":"polygon","price_usd":2622.4290334646125,"price_eth":1739.6856993161678,"amount":9.225,"amount_in":9.225,"amount_out":0.0}],"tokens_out":[{"address":"0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174","symbol":"USDC","amm":"uniswap_v3","network":"polygon","price_usd":0.9997410796727977,"price_eth":0.6633871411260988,"amount":24193.850184,"amount_in":0.0,"amount_out":24193.850184}],"pair_address":"0x45dda9cb7c25131df268515131f647d726f50608","wallet_address":"0x0dd89655c6ee8d660c00667625434b53112bd32e","wallet_category":"heavy","transaction_type":"swap"},{"amm":"uniswap_v3","chain_id":137,"direction":"out","transaction_address":"0x5d0bed394c1a35dcc12a70863b499807f1994cd2b3d4f53f3ebadebf4cf02018","timestamp":1645650603,"block_number":25270534,"to":"0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45","sender":"0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45","amount_usd":4839.085854444992,"tokens_in":[{"address":"0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619","symbol":"WETH","amm":"uniswap_v3","network":"polygon","price_usd":2623.789185554057,"price_eth":1742.0049634816962,"amount":1.845,"amount_in":1.845,"amount_out":0.0}],"tokens_out":[{"address":"0x0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270","symbol":"WMATIC","amm":"uniswap_v3","network":"polygon","price_usd":1.5061892707297249,"price_eth":1.0,"amount":3212.8006409848686,"amount_in":0.0,"amount_out":3212.8006409848686}],"pair_address":"0x86f1d8390222a3691c28938ec7404a1661e618e0","wallet_address":"0x0dd89655c6ee8d660c00667625434b53112bd32e","wallet_category":"heavy","transaction_type":"swap"},{"amm":"uniswap_v3","chain_id":137,"direction":"out","transaction_address":"0x5d0bed394c1a35dcc12a70863b499807f1994cd2b3d4f53f3ebadebf4cf02018","timestamp":1645650603,"block_number":25270534,"to":"0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45","sender":"0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45","amount_usd":3235.066832050649,"tokens_in":[{"address":"0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619","symbol":"WETH","amm":"uniswap_v3","network":"polygon","price_usd":2629.3618746410916,"price_eth":1744.2848570041135,"amount":1.23,"amount_in":1.23,"amount_out":0.0}],"tokens_out":[{"address":"0x769434dca303597c8fc4997bf3dab233e961eda2","symbol":"XSGD","amm":"uniswap_v3","network":"polygon","price_usd":0.7445968945528842,"price_eth":0.4939560051688091,"amount":4344.722434,"amount_in":0.0,"amount_out":4344.722434}],"pair_address":"0x8eb315dbd94469016e84098184dd55c1af2edabb","wallet_address":"0x0dd89655c6ee8d660c00667625434b53112bd32e","wallet_category":"heavy","transaction_type":"swap"},{"amm":"jetswap","chain_id":137,"direction":"in","transaction_address":"0x60f4709e1f7a37033e23106d068fbe248a734211b598a73c86d5c2c0a2ed00a7","timestamp":1645650603,"block_number":25270534,"to":"0x0dfbf1a50bdcb570bd0ff7bb307313b553a02598","sender":"0xd12bcdfb9a39be79da3bdf02557efdcd5ca59e77","amount_usd":40.00789545980349,"tokens_in":[{"address":"0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174","symbol":"USDC","amm":"jetswap","network":"polygon","price_usd":0.9997410796727977,"price_eth":0.6633871411260988,"amount":40.018257,"amount_in":40.018257,"amount_out":0.0}],"tokens_out":[{"address":"0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619","symbol":"WETH","amm":"jetswap","network":"polygon","price_usd":2632.2662609672825,"price_eth":1746.211589545771,"amount":0.015208203772373943,"amount_in":0.0,"amount_out":0.015208203772373943}],"pair_address":"0xfeff91c350bb564ca5dc7d6f7dcd12ac092f94ff","wallet_address":"0x325a56ae86ccd523beebb3bad693257c60300032","wallet_category":"noob","transaction_type":"swap"},{"amm":"quickswap","chain_id":137,"direction":"out","transaction_address":"0x60f4709e1f7a37033e23106d068fbe248a734211b598a73c86d5c2c0a2ed00a7","timestamp":1645650603,"block_number":25270534,"to":"0xd12bcdfb9a39be79da3bdf02557efdcd5ca59e77","sender":"0xd12bcdfb9a39be79da3bdf02557efdcd5ca59e77","amount_usd":39.94507652391958,"tokens_in":[{"address":"0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619","symbol":"WETH","amm":"quickswap","network":"polygon","price_usd":2634.080184385698,"price_eth":1748.8374373491106,"amount":0.015208203772373943,"amount_in":0.015208203772373943,"amount_out":0.0}],"tokens_out":[{"address":"0x0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270","symbol":"WMATIC","amm":"quickswap","network":"polygon","price_usd":1.5061892707297249,"price_eth":1.0,"amount":26.52062214237313,"amount_in":0.0,"amount_out":26.52062214237313}],"pair_address":"0x0dfbf1a50bdcb570bd0ff7bb307313b553a02598","wallet_address":"0x325a56ae86ccd523beebb3bad693257c60300032","wallet_category":"noob","transaction_type":"swap"},{"amm":"sushiswap","chain_id":137,"direction":"out","transaction_address":"0xacac09e20049289cce1f5b81f2512e429abdbccca8eb9e84c1c65f09e2a61877","timestamp":1645650603,"block_number":25270534,"to":"0x1b02da8cb0d097eb8d57a175b88c7d8b47997506","sender":"0x1b02da8cb0d097eb8d57a175b88c7d8b47997506","amount_usd":67.53023516550269,"tokens_in":[{"address":"0x53e0bca35ec356bd5dddfebbd1fc0fd03fabad39","symbol":"LINK","amm":"sushiswap","network":"polygon","price_usd":13.865995104068453,"price_eth":9.198522850956453,"amount":2.435102373059705,"amount_in":2.435102373059705,"amount_out":0.0},{"address":"0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619","symbol":"WETH","amm":"sushiswap","network":"polygon","price_usd":2629.3618746410916,"price_eth":1744.2848570041135,"amount":0.012841563539959779,"amount_in":0.012841563539959779,"amount_out":0.0}],"tokens_out":[],"pair_address":"0x74d23f21f780ca26b47db16b0504f2e3832b9321","wallet_address":"0x2e822887361d618ad80a4fbe24da7d8521f712c2","wallet_category":null,"transaction_type":"mint"},{"amm":"uniswap_v3","chain_id":137,"direction":"out","transaction_address":"0xc50d7efd9150cfc9fdd04d31309b601371adb074bf561de09368efd461fcc50a","timestamp":1645650603,"block_number":25270534,"to":"0xeb3d51c1740b71d2c336806e04897b1568bbfd7c","sender":"0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564","amount_usd":2077.9006189538604,"tokens_in":[{"address":"0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619","symbol":"WETH","amm":"uniswap_v3","network":"polygon","price_usd":2625.4754887225076,"price_eth":1741.7066785602713,"amount":0.792,"amount_in":0.792,"amount_out":0.0}],"tokens_out":[{"address":"0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174","symbol":"USDC","amm":"uniswap_v3","network":"polygon","price_usd":0.9997410796727977,"price_eth":0.6633871411260988,"amount":2078.438769,"amount_in":0.0,"amount_out":2078.438769}],"pair_address":"0x45dda9cb7c25131df268515131f647d726f50608","wallet_address":"0x0000000078b7076edd7c78e7873e39c446284480","wallet_category":"bot","transaction_type":"swap"},{"amm":"dfyn","chain_id":137,"direction":"in","transaction_address":"0xd68524a01d4f1a471d165d27665bf82e95e55136b0e70f08a990dc75d0ab0826","timestamp":1645650603,"block_number":25270534,"to":"0x64ac1107923413b6faf0168e2063c1d4cb01bc9b","sender":"0x139b341c75d016a2df262f9babb4f8c794484d41","amount_usd":1.3255504083616483,"tokens_in":[{"address":"0xc168e40227e4ebd8c1cae80f7a55a4f0e6d66c97","symbol":"DFYN","amm":"dfyn","network":"polygon","price_usd":0.09275529258662499,"price_eth":0.06153266837335598,"amount":14.33377439994291,"amount_in":14.33377439994291,"amount_out":0.0}],"tokens_out":[{"address":"0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619","symbol":"WETH","amm":"dfyn","network":"polygon","price_usd":2629.3618746410916,"price_eth":1744.2848570041135,"amount":0.000504133881739875,"amount_in":0.0,"amount_out":0.000504133881739875}],"pair_address":"0x6fa867bbfdd025780a8cfe988475220aff51fb8b","wallet_address":"0x24a66f8dd7abdbf6f923795a5d4a009ba1b5e011","wallet_category":"heavy","transaction_type":"swap"}]}
```

Comment: You need to post the JSON, but are you certain it is an array (e.g. `[{"amm"="xyz"...}]`)?

Comment: Copy the json into the clipboard, then "Edit/Paste Special/Paste Json as classes".  This will create classes that are compatible with the json.   There are also several web site that will do the same thing with more options.  There is no reason to write your own classes in 2022.

Comment: I just posted the Json Results as an Edit . Now that i am looking at it, is it because i am not deserializing the "total" and "data"? I started my deserialization at [{ 'amm":...}]

Comment: I got it solved. was not parsing correctly. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Was not deserializing the upper class and array. It is now working. thanks for your help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).